# Screen Switching in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had made a registration form and a button at the bottom to submit the data in NSUerDefaults. When i click submit it switches to another view controller screen through show Segue and a back button appears at the top left of the new screen. I want that if i hit submit button it should switch to another view controller screen but the button at the top left should not appear. The previous screen should finish.

Comment: I already given solution for this ... @Hamza

Comment: I had use a show segue from registration form when i submit the data it moves to another screen but a back button appear at  the top left of new screen when i click that back button it moves back to registration screen and shows the filled fields. i want just to move to next screen not the back option. @NAVEENKUMAR

Comment: in that view u can set     **self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;** in ur next scene(in witch vc u want to hide back button).

Comment: My old problem is still there that issue is not resolved @NAVEENKUMAR

Comment: can we place on view controller to another? @NAVEENKUMAR

Comment: what it means:  can we place on view controller to another?  I did't get it

Comment: when user registered the successful message appears and it goes to home screen where there option of left menu bar items. i have connected the register button to home screen with Show Segue. But when it goes to home screen the back button appears and i have used ur code of hiding back button, the button get hide but left menu bar icon not appear as it appears before. @NAVEENKUMAR

Comment: u asked for hiding the back button .... @Hamza. u need to write this in witch vc u don't need to show back button

Comment: actually I'm want to store registration form data using Json web services and when i hit register button it should store data and show message success and than switch to home screen and home screen should look same as it was looking before with the left menu bar icon on top left. @NAVEENKUMAR

Comment: ok .... what issues ur facing for that

Comment: the issue is when i hit register button it moves me to home screen but the left menu bar button not appears. I have conected register button with home screen through show segue. @NAVEENKUMAR

Comment: with of seeing ur code I can't say anything

Answer (score 0):

If you want to finish the registration form view controller, You need to change the root view controller like this after saving data in user defaults.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = [[otherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"otherViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: In your submit button action . After saving your data into user defaults.

Comment: it is is displaying error that the other view controller is not in user interface. @Muhammad Khaliq ur Rehman

Comment: Please share your view controller name which you want to show.

Comment: i want to show FindViewController. @Muhammad Khaliq ur Rehman

Comment: Replace otherViewController with FindViewController in above code. Then use it.